# How can I check changes on a switch in a fragment class within the class (android studio)?

Tags: android, fragment

I want to check the switch state in a class that extends from fragment. I'm trying to check if any changes occurred in a switch state (in android studio, using fragments), but when I check or uncheck the switch, nothing happens. I tried to get it outside the class but the switch is null because the view is not ready yet in the UI as I understand. When I do it within the class, even though it is not null, apparently the CheckedListener doesn't seem to work.

```
public class Controls extends Fragment {
    static Switch sw_motor_au;
    View view;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreateView(inflater,container,savedInstanceState);
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.controls_layout, container, false);
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.controls_layout, container, false);
    }
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        Switch onOffSwitch = (Switch)  
        view.findViewById(R.id.MotorAutomatico);
        onOffSwitch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                ProviderAppContext ac=(ProviderAppContext)(ProviderAppContext) ProviderAppContext.getAppContext();
                Log.v("Switch State=", ""+isChecked);
                Toast.makeText(ac, "llegó", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

XML segment for that switch:

```
    <Switch
        android:id="@+id/MotorAutomatico"
        android:layout_width="340dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:text="Accionar motor automáticamente"
        android:textOff="Apagado"
        android:textOn="Encendido"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        app:showText="true"

        />
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because you inflated your layout twice and used the wrong one for referencing the switch.

```
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreateView(inflater,container,savedInstanceState);
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.controls_layout, container, false);
        return view;
    }
```

P.S - Don't store your inflated view in a variable, it's already accessible after `onCreateView` completes using `getView()` method.